# Prove that $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f(x) = \infty$ iff $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(\frac{1}{x}) = \infty$ Explanation of solution and concept.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Prove that $$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}f(x) = \infty \\ \text{iff} \\ \lim_{x \to \infty}f\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg) = \infty$$

I'm confused by the reasoning behind a solution that I found for this question from Spivak. This solution solves the problem proving the "if" part (i.e proving in $\Leftarrow$ direction).

This is the solution presented:

[image]

Here is the start of my problems. If we are going to prove this direction we are assuming $$\lim_{x \to \infty}f\bigg(\frac{1}{x}\bigg) = \infty$$

is true. But the definition of this object is: **For all $N > 0$, there exists a $M > 0$ s.t for all $x$ if $x > M$ then $f(\frac{1}{x}) > N$**

So how is it that $f(1/x) < N$ for $x > M$ is satisfied? That is not the definition of the above object. Then the following manipulation that "If $0 < x < \frac{1}{M}$, then $x > M$"....that's not true either, it would be $M < \frac{1}{x}$ if we manipulated it.

As can be seen I'm having difficulty reconciling how to fit one definition into the other. Some clarification on what I'm not understanding about this would be helpful.

Comment: It was a typo. It must say $f(1/x)>N$

Comment: They’re doing the obvious thing — substituting x=1/x’. But unfortunately they use the same letter for both making it very confusing

Comment: @soktinpk so what they are trying to get across is that If we allow $ 0 < \frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{M}$ then we can conclude what we want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it step by step, goal: fitting the definitions.

First of all, what you want to prove is $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = \infty$. Then by the definition, you need to show that 
\begin{equation}
\forall M > 0, \exists N > 0 \quad s.t. \quad x \leq 1/N \implies f(x) \geq M
\end{equation}
On the other hand, what you have is 
$$
\forall M > 0, \exists N > 0 \quad s.t. \quad y \geq N \implies f(1/y) \geq M
$$
Here, $y \geq N \iff 1/y \leq 1/N$. Then let $x = 1/y$, you get
\begin{align}
\forall M > 0, \exists N > 0 \quad s.t. \quad x \leq 1/N \implies f(x) \geq M
\end{align}
You get what you want.

Comment: Remark: It can be $x\leq N$ or $x\leq 1/N$

Comment: If I was working through it, I wouldn't be able to state $x \leq \frac{1}{N}$ right away because I "wouldn't know " what that bound exactly is until I unravel the definitions. But I do agree and like your process.

Comment: @JohnMedina-Diaz Yeah, but I made this since I thought it's easier to understand the essence of the proof and definition. And, M, N usually denotes the large interger, thus I did in this way.

Comment: @dc3rd If you can fit the definition then you can prove this statement. Roughly speaking, x goes to infinite is corresponding to that for 1/x goes to zero, then that's what you know. Finally plug what you konw into the definition, you get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way,

Let $N>0$ (arbitrary), then $\exists M>0: f(1/x)>N, \forall x>M$ (by hypothesis). Thus $f(x)>N, \forall 1/x>M$, which is equivalent to $f(x)>N, \forall 0<x<1/M.$ Then let $\delta = 1/M$, so you get: $\exists \delta>0: f(x)>N, \forall 0<|x-0|<\delta$

Comment: In this case you "substituted"  $x = \frac{1}{x}$ into the expression and proceeded....

Comment: Yes, I substituted. But be careful, that doesn´t mean that I stated x=1/x.

Comment: You can do that, I don´t know if that symbol property owns a special name, but get accustomed to it.

Comment: For completeness doing the proof the other way: I have the relationship $x < \delta \rightarrow \frac{1}{\delta}<\frac{1}{x}$. So if we let $M = \frac{1}{\delta}$ and $x = \frac{1}{x}$ then I can conclude the if and only if part.

Comment: Yes!! But: it is better this $0<x<\delta$. P.S. $1/x\rightarrow x$ could be better.

Comment: Nice. What do you mean by $\frac{1}{x} \to x$ could be better?

Comment: Just instead of saying $equals$

Comment: Ah ok....Thanks for your help. This changing of notation is going to be tedious to get comfortable with...